# Could not create file /target/streams/compile/run/$global/streams/outjava.io.IOException:Too many open files

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I am working on a project where I have used `play sbt` .I have my application and that was working fine, but from some time it is giving me the error like -

Could not create file

```
/target/streams/compile/run/$global/streams/outjava.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:10)
    at sbt.IO$.touch(IO.scala:143)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.make(Streams.scala:129)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.text(Streams.scala:113)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:124)
    at sbt.std.TaskStreams$class.log(Streams.scala:56)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log$lzycompute(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.std.Streams$$anon$3$$anon$2.log(Streams.scala:102)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$$anonfun$logIncomplete$2.log$1(EvaluateTask.scala:269)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$$anonfun$logIncomplete$2.apply(EvaluateTask.scala:273)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$$anonfun$logIncomplete$2.apply(EvaluateTask.scala:268)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.logIncomplete(EvaluateTask.scala:268)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.logIncResult(EvaluateTask.scala:261)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:348)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:361)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:64)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:62)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:293)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:62)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:71)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyDynamicTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:112)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyDynamicTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:110)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:244)
    at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:241)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Because of this , whenever I get this error , After that I am not able to do any operation on application. I searched it.But I am not able to solve this. I am using `ubuntu 14.04` . `Scala version is 2.11.8` .Thanks for your time .Any will help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two options:

1. Just increase possible number of opened files, like described [here](http://posidev.com/blog/2009/06/04/set-ulimit-parameters-on-ubuntu/). To sum up, you should add lines like these to file `/etc/security/limits.conf` and reboot:

`user  soft  nofile 9000`

`user  hard  nofile 65000`

Replace `user` with name of user who runs application. Also you may play a bit with actual amount of open files. It's simple method, but it requires root and you may encounter the same problem again later. It's kind of workaround.

2. Discover, why do you have this problem with methods described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181215/too-many-open-files-how-to-find-the-culprit#181408). It can be harder, but you may find root of problem and just get rid of it.

Comment: I have used this but no luck with this.